# External function call solidity

Tags: solidity

Assuming that I don’t know the contract A, I just know its address, and that it has a `setNumber` method that I want to call it from contract B.

I want to call the function `setNumber` in contract A, using the method `callsetNumbercontractA` in contract B.

**How to reproduce:**

- Deploy both contracts
- Copy contract A address and use the function `setcontract` in contract B
- Now try to use the function `callsetNumbercontractA` in contract B

It will fail and I can't get why.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.12;
contract A {
    event lmao (string);
    uint public x;
    function hello () public {
        emit lmao ('YES');
    }
    function setNumber (uint n) public {
        x=n;
    }
} 

pragma solidity 0.5.12;
contract B{
    address public to;    
    function callcontractA () public {
       to.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("hello()"));
    }   
    function setcontract (address x) public{
        to = x;
    }   
    function callsetNumbercontractA () public {
        // I wanna set var x (in A) to 10
       to.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setNumber(uint)",10));
    }
}
```

Ropsten transactions:

- [callcontractA's 3rd event log “yes”](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x64a2ff0a6580d6da609bec122c6a616c64b806fe94975b05fde910ab328bd665#eventlog)
- [callsetNumbercontractA`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x98a7d4ce3c730fe5c24dc759680a51c326515f67a04d13c45af02e967bc5b977)

Comment: ? What is missing

Comment: What is `Looks like I can use callcontractA() but not callsetNumbercontractA ()` supposed to mean??? Have you looked at the code formatting???

Comment: Sorry for that I edited my post. Hope it's more readable.

Comment: I've fixed it a little bit, guess you could probably fix it further.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reasoning in your question for not using this:

```
contract IA {
    function setNumber(uint n) public;
}

contract B {
    IA public a;    
    function setContract(IA _a) public {
        a = _a;
    }   
    function setNumber() public {
        a.setNumber(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question (I am not practical at all excuse me).
As far as I understand, in order to follow you guide, I should have both contracts on the same solidity file. Is it right? In my case, the contracts are in totally different solidity files.

Comment: @Dani69654: `I should have both contracts on the same solidity file` - no you don't (do you see both contracts in my example above?).